# Why is my CFRunLoopTimer not firing?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation

I have a `CFRunLoopTimer` created within a C++ class as shown below:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

void cClass::StartTimer()
{      
  if(!mActiveSenseTimer)
  {
    CFTimeInterval TIMER_INTERVAL = 5;
    CFRunLoopTimerContext TimerContext = {0, this, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFAbsoluteTime FireTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() + TIMER_INTERVAL;
    mTimer = CFRunLoopTimerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                  FireTime,
                                  0, 0, 0,
                                  ActiveSenseTimerCallback,
                                  &TimerContext);

    NSLog(@"RunLoop:0x%x, TimerIsValid:%d, TimeIsNow:%f, TimerWillFireAt:%f",
          CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
          CFRunLoopTimerIsValid(mActiveSenseTimer),
          CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(),
          FireTime);
  }
}

void ActiveSenseTimerCallback(CFRunLoopTimerRef timer, void *info)
{
  NSLog(@"Timeout");
  CFRunLoopTimerContext TimerContext;
  TimerContext.version = 0;

  CFRunLoopTimerGetContext(timer, &TimerContext);
  ((cClass *)TimerContext.info)->Timeout();
}
```

Calling `cClass::StartTimer()` results in the following log output:

> RunLoop:0x7655d60, TimerIsValid:1, TimeIsNow:389196910.537962, TimerWillFireAt:389196915.537956

However, my timer never fires. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopTimerRef/Reference/reference.html)

> A timer needs to be added to a run loop mode before it will fire. To add the timer to a run loop, use [CFRunLoopAddTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html). A timer can be registered to only one run loop at a time, although it can be in multiple modes within that run loop.

Also make sure your run loop doesn't die before the timer fires.